# dmesg shows APCI BIOS error AE_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: ubuntu, acpi, dmesg

I am seeing this in dmesg startup, over and over, after like 20 times, it moves on.

What does the error mean and should I be worried?

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3

Everything appears to be working, but I would like to understand this.

```
[    0.252186] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.I2CA.WT1A], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
[    0.252191] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
[    0.252193] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Device (0x5B82)
```

Much further down in the log, there is another error that mentions ACPI, I would also like to know what it means, and if they are related:

```
[    1.036755] ACPI Error: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000007) is beyond end of object (length 0x6) (20181213/exoparg2-396)
[    1.037678] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PLD]
[    1.038155] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PLD]
[    1.038628] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.S0D2.D2A0.BYUP.BYD8.XHC1.RHUB.PRT6._PLD, AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20181213/psparse-531)
```

Comment: It's an unresolved issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1981783